# Creating a global object in QT GUI

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create an object called x from a class "Fan" inside the QT GUI mainwindow file, where I want it to be global. I want QT's button slot functions to be able to perform operations on the object. However, a compiler error "error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed" always occurs. Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_btOn_clicked();

    void on_btOff_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Fan x; // This doesn't work
    Fan * x; // This doesn't either
    int x; // This does work
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And here is the cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "fan.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btOn_clicked()
{
    ui->lblState->setText("Fan is on");
}

void MainWindow::on_btOff_clicked()
{
    x.turnOff(); // This does not work of course
    x->turnOff(); // Or this
    ui->lblState->setText("Fan is off");
}
```

I already told the cpp file to include the Fan class from the fan.h file. If I create the object within the window constructor, it initializes fine but is not global. Also, there is no circular inclusion of header files. Fan class does not include mainwindow.

Perhaps I don't know how to search for it, but I've already done some research into it to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the fan.cpp file

```
#include "fan.h"

Fan::Fan(){
    speed = 0;
    isOn = false;
}
void Fan::setSpeed(int s){
    speed = s;
}
int Fan::getSpeed(){
    return speed;
}
void Fan::turnOn(){
    isOn = true;
    speed = 1;
}
void Fan::turnOff(){
    isOn = false;
    speed = 0;
}
bool Fan::getState(){
    return isOn;
}
```

And the fan.h file:

```
#ifndef FAN_H
#define FAN_H


class Fan
{
private:
    int speed;
    bool isOn;
public:
    Fan();
    void setSpeed(int);
    void turnOn();
    void turnOff();
    int getSpeed();
    bool getState();
};

#endif // FAN_H
```

Comment: You have to include `fan.h` in the `mainwindow.h` because `Fan` class participates in the `MainWindow` class declaration.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried that, but now I get an "unresolved external symbol" error from the on_btOn_clicked() and on_btOff_clicked() functions specifically in the lines x.turnOn() and x.turnOff(). Why is this?

Comment: @AllanVindel, that indicates that you didn't compile your `Fan` class (.cpp), or `Fan::turnOn()` function has no definition.

Comment: I just added the fan.cpp and fan.h file codes to my question. The functions are defined. I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Do you compile `fan.cpp` in your project too?

Comment: I found the solution. It seems like compiling issues were the problem, aside from not including fan.h in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to include or declare the class Fan in your `Header File`. If you use

```
Fan * x;
```

You could use

```
class Fan;
```

as a forward declaration at the beginning of your `Header File`. The Compiler only need to know that there is a class called `Fan` but inside the `Header` you only use a pointer. Butt don't forget to `#include` the real file in your CPP file.

If you use

```
Fan x;
```

you have to `#include` the `Fan.h` in your `Header-File`

Comment: Thank you. I already included the "fan.h" file in the mainwindow header file, and now the error I get is "unresolved external symbol" from the on_btOn_clicked() and on_btOff_clicked() functions specifically in the lines x.turnOn() and x.turnOff(). It seems like a step forward. Any idea on why that happens?